# Lubuntu 14.04 (after partition resize) seems doesn't boot if dpm radeon is required in grub.conf

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, ati, lubuntu

**premise: partition editing:**
After a full backup, I've performed some action to gain more space with my /home and /root partition with Lubuntu 14.04.03 LTS, with Gpartedlive.

**premise: video card**
I've a (video card) ati hd3650AGP, fully supported by free radeon driver as RV635. This hardware **was** configured with the line "`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.dpm=1"`" in `/etc/default/grub.conf`  to enable saving energy (it reduces clock of gpu and ram consequently the stand-by temperature of 10°C, or more!). Since this configuration was done (maybe one year ago) has always worked well (low temperature, good performance ec..).

**Question - problem:

Now I've noticed that lubuntu starts only if I remove this (above mentioned) line from grub.conf, othewise it simply stops the boot (monitor displays OSD info as disconnected "vga no signal"), how resolve?** Below an attempt to describe with more details two steps previously described.

--

**Details -Partition editing-:**
Specifically, I've copied (there's this option in Gparted "copy/paste partition") /home to another, bigger, place, and resized, root / partition.
Then fixed some little issues:
-at boot I've told to "grub rescue>" prompt where is now / partition
-fixed /etc/fstab (uuuid were cloned with above mentioned copy option), all seems correct (/home is mounted)

**Details -Video card-:**
About Radeon driver I've followed these [info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver).
Below the output of my video card to three command to gather information about its state, **I think there are some suspect messages with second command below** (`LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo`):

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
AMD/ATI] RV635 PRO [Radeon HD 3650 AGP] [1002:9596]


LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo
name of display: :0
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI3 capable
libGL: pci id for fd 4: 1002:9596, driver r600
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/r600_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/r600_dri.so
libGL: driver does not expose __driDriverGetExtensions_r600(): /usr/lib 
/i386-linux-gnu/dri/r600_dri.so: undefined symbol: 
__driDriverGetExtensions_r600
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/myusername/.drirc: No such file 
or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/myusername/.drirc: No such file or
directory.
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
--CUT--TOO LONG--


dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
[25.736186] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[26.312791] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[26.312883] fb: conflicting fb hw usage radeondrmfb vs VESA VGA -
removing generic driver
[26.317183] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RV635 0x1002:0x9596
0x1787:0x0028).
[26.317207] [drm] register mmio base: 0xFD600000
[26.317208] [drm] register mmio size: 65536
[26.318551] radeon 0000:01:00.0: putting AGP V3 device into 8x mode
[26.318555] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 256M 0xE0000000 - 0xEFFFFFFF
[26.318562] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 512M 0xC0000000 - 0xDFFFFFFF
(512M used)
[26.318565] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=512M, BAR=256M
[26.318567] [drm] RAM width 128bits DDR
[26.326238] [drm] radeon: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[26.326240] [drm] radeon: 256M of GTT memory ready.
[26.326256] [drm] Loading RV635 Microcode
[26.824726] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 65536, num gpu pages 65536
[26.832722] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB disabled
[26.832734] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr
0x00000000e0000004 and cpu addr 0xf8452004
[26.832738] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 
0x00000000e0000c0c and cpu addr 0xf8452c0c
[26.832742] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[26.832744] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[26.832767] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[26.865374] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[26.865386] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 3 usecs
[26.865593] [drm] Enabling audio 0 support
[26.865624] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[26.865649] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[26.870130] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[26.870133] [drm] Connector 0:
[26.870135] [drm]   DVI-I-1
[26.870137] [drm]   HPD1
[26.870140] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e50 0x7e50 0x7e54 0x7e54 0x7e58 0x7e58 
0x7e5c 0x7e5c
[26.870141] [drm]   Encoders:
[26.870143] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[26.870145] [drm]     CRT2: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC2
[26.870146] [drm] Connector 1:
[26.870148] [drm]   DIN-1
[26.870149] [drm]   Encoders:
[26.870151] [drm]     TV1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC2
[26.870153] [drm] Connector 2:
[26.870154] [drm]   DVI-I-2
[26.870156] [drm]   HPD2
[26.870158] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e40 0x7e40 0x7e44 0x7e44 0x7e48 0x7e48  
0x7e4c 0x7e4c
[26.870160] [drm]   Encoders:
[26.870161] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[26.870163] [drm]     DFP2: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_LVTMA
[26.870209] [drm] Internal thermal controller with fan control
[26.870286] [drm] radeon: power management initialized
[27.013782] [drm] fb mappable at 0xC00C1000
[27.013787] [drm] vram apper at 0xC0000000
[27.013789] [drm] size 5324800
[27.013791] [drm] fb depth is 24
[27.013793] [drm]    pitch is 5888
[27.014772] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[27.110874] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[27.110877] radeon 0000:01:00.0: registered panic notifier
[27.111432] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.36.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on 
minor 0
```

Comment: I've solved:   first I've reinstalled the package "libgl1-mesa-dri", I suspect this wasn't necessary.  Then I Edited the above mentioned 'grub.conf' adding 'radeon.dpm=0' (explicit disabling). rebooted (as expected nothing has changed). Then changed the parameter to 'radeon.dpm=1', and after a reboot it's ok. **I see temperture passed from 58/60°C in idle to 40/42°C.**

Comment: Don't add "Solved" into the title. Write an answer and accept 24 hours later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I've reinstalled the package "libgl1-mesa-dri" (I suspect this wasn't necessary).
2. Then I Edited the above mentioned `/etc/default/grub.conf` adding `radeon.dpm=0`
   (explicit disabling power saving). Note: follow instruction in [wiki
   radeon driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Kernel_3.11.x_.28Ubuntu_13.10.2FSaucy.29_and_Later) (*remembering* `sudo update-grub`)
3. **rebooted** (as expected nothing has changed).
4. Then changed the parameter to `radeon.dpm=1` (update gurb as above linked ecc..)
5. reboot
6. it's ok: **I see temperture passed from 58/60°C in idle to
   40/42°C.**

kernel version:3.13.0-65-generic
Lubuntu LTS 14.04